# Windows Update Cleanup - Disk Cleanup via script/command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, disk-space-utilization

We've noticed that when running Disk Cleanup utility manually on a windows server 2019 that 'Windows Update Cleanup' takes up a substantial amount of space. Is there away to clean this up via a command prompt/powershell

I've looked at a number of scripts which do not clear this down. Could anyone advise what is the best way to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Microsoft way:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Update Cleanup" /V "StateFlags0000" /T REG_DWORD /D "2" /F

cleanmgr.exe /SAGERUN:0
```

Logfiles are located here:

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\setupcln\setupact.log
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\setupcln\setuperr.log

C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log

DISM may also be an option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back, the following looks to work dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase but does seem quite excessive.

cleanmgr.exe /SAGERUN:0 prompted for user input.